# Adding parentheses to an expression tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, expression-trees

I'm trying to write a function that given a tree, creates an infix expression, with only necessary parentheses. For example if the expression ((a-3)-(b-5)) had been entered into a tree, this function would return the string a-3-(b-5) or ((a-3)*(b-5)) returns (a-3)*(b-5) [For some reason it won't display * between those expressions]. I currently have a function that will enclose the whole expression in parentheses, for the first example it returns (a-3-b-5). Could someone explain what's causing it to a) not add brackets to each single expression, and b) how to modify it to only add required parentheses.

Edit: Modified slightly so that every expression is now given parentheses but not the entire expression. Now produces (a-3)-(b-5) as output.

```
private String inorder(ExpTree t) {
    if (t != null) {
        //if node and left child are operators
        if (t.type == 2) {
            if (getPri(t) <= getPri(parent) && t != parent) {
                strBuf.append('(');
            }
        }
        inorder(t.lChild, t);
        strBuf.append(t.leafVal);
        inorder(t.rChild, t);
        //if node and right child are operators
        if (t.type == 2) {
            if (getPri(t) <= getPri(parent) && t != parent) {
                strBuf.append(')');
            }
        }
    }
    return strBuf.toString();

private int getPri(ExpTree t) {
    String leaf = "";
    if (t.type == 2) {
        leaf = t.leafVal.toString();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    if (leaf == "*" || leaf == "%" || leaf == "/") {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (leaf == "+" || leaf == "-") {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ExpTree class

```
public class ExpTree {
private int type;
private Object leafVal;
private ExpTree lChild, rChild;
public static final int NUM = 0, VAL = 1, OP = 2;

public ExpTree(int type, Object leafVal, ExpTree l, ExpTree r) {
    this.type = type;
    this.leafVal = leafVal;
    this.lChild = l;
    this.rChild = r;
}
```